# Date Validation not working correctly

Tags: vba, validation, excel, date

I am trying to validate a date that is entered into a textbox on a user form. When I enter for example `23/7/15` the code works fine and gives me a value as the date entered is valid, when I enter `32/7/2015` I get a message that I program telling the user that they have entered a wrong date but if I enter `32/7/15` it sets the date in the code to some date in 1932 and as this is a valid date it does not throw the error. Below is the code that I am using. Is there anyway to validate `32/7/15`?

```
Private Function errorCheckingDate(box1, message) As Boolean '<============= Returns a True or a False
    If Not IsDate(box1) Then '<============================================= Checks to see if entered value is date or not
        MsgBox message, vbExclamation, "Invalid Selection" '<=============== Displays a messgae box if not date
        box1.SetFocus '<==================================================== Puts cursor back to the offending box
        errorCheckingDate = True '<========================================= Sets function to True
    End If
End Function
```

box1 is just the value of the textbox once it has been converted to a date. Below is the conversion

```
        secondSelectedStr = Format(DateTextBox.value, "dd-mm-yy") '<===== Convert to correct format
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You say that `box1` is the value of the textbox after it is converted into a date, but you are attempting to use it like it is the entire textbox, not just the value (on the `box1.SetFocus` line).

Comment: Does using `CDate` make a difference? `secondSelectedStr = CDate(Format(DateTextBox.value, ...`

Comment: @JoshuaRoss Sorry I forgot to remove that part. It is not supposed to have the setfocus bit. I had put that in to try something.

Comment: Well, since July 32nd does not exist, Excel assumes you are entering the date in a different order and switches day with year. The outcome is the date 15th July, 1932. I am currently having a look on how to catch an error like that. If you want to force a format, you can do this with `Format()`, but this won't work if the outcome is invalid, so your error check is bypassed again.

Comment: You could use `split` on the date and split by "-" and test the individual components: days less than 31, months less than 12 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys but I need to accommodate for leap years and other things. As the `isdate` function works if the date is entered in the form 1/1/2015 I have just used the `len()` function to make sure that the date entered is of a certain length. Below is the code that I used. Thanks for you help once again. :)

```
Private Function errorCheckingDate(box1, message) As Boolean '<============= Returns a True or a False
If Not IsDate(box1) Or Len(box1) < 8 Or Len(box1) > 10 Then '<============================================= Checks to see if entered value is date or not
    MsgBox message, vbExclamation, "Invalid Selection" '<=============== Displays a messgae box if not date
    box1.SetFocus '<==================================================== Puts cursor back to the offending box
    errorCheckingDate = True '<========================================= Sets function to True
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using `IsDate` you could use your own custom function likened to it.

```
Function isValidDate(d as String) as Boolean
Dim parts as Variant
Dim months29 as variant
Dim months30 as variant
Dim months31 as variant
months29 = Array(2)
months30 = Array(4, 6, 9, 11)
months31 = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)
parts = Split(d, "-")
if parts(2) mod 4 = 0 then
    daysLeapYear = 28
else:
    daysLeapYear = 29
end if
if ((IsInArray(parts(0), months29) and parts(1) <= daysLeapYear) or _
   (IsInArray(parts(0), months30) and parts(1) < 31) or _
   (IsInArray(parts(0), months31) and parts(1) < 32)) and _
    parts(2) < 16 then
        isValidDate = True
else:
        isValidDate = False
end if
end function

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

This should cover most cases. Not sure how detailed you feel you need to be. `IsInArray` courtesy of @JimmyPena.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ordering issue, VBA will also try to adapt invalid date ranges to a proper date. For example, this has always been a neat technique to get the X day of the year:

```
d = DateSerial(2015, 1, X)
```

`X` can be really any number here (up to the limits of the data type, of course). If `X` is 500, it will produce the date `2016-5-14`. So the `mm/dd` vs `dd/mm` vs `yy/mm/dd` issue *plus* the fact that VBA accepts numbers *outside* valid ranges are both troublesome.

Without range-checking each date component (where you have to consider leap years and whatnot), I think the best solution is to just have VBA create your date and then test it to ensure it's what you're expecting. For example:

```
' Get the date components (assuming d/m/yy)...
Dim a As Variant
a = Split(strDate, "/")

' Need 3 components...
If UBound(a) <> 2 Then MsgBox "Invalid date": Exit Sub

' Create the date. This will hardly ever fail. 
' VBA will create some kind of date using whatever numbers you throw at it.
Dim d As Date
d = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))

' Make sure the date VBA created matches what we expected...
If Day(d) <> CInt(a(0)) Then MsgBox "Invalid day": Exit Sub
If Month(d) <> CInt(a(1)) Then MsgBox "Invalid month": Exit Sub
If Right$(Year(d), 2) <> a(2) Then MsgBox "Invalid year": Exit Sub
```

You could throw that into a subroutine (you may have noticed the `Exit Sub` statements) to validate the date that gets entered. The `TextBox_Exit` event would work well. That way, you could set `Cancel = True` to prevent the user from leaving the textbox with an invalid date.